# Source command not working in a bash script

Tags: bash

Consider this code I run directly in bash (Mac):

```
> source <(echo "ABC=1")
> echo $ABC
1
```

Now, if I put these two lines in a test.sh script and execute:

```
#!/bin/bash
source <(echo "ABC=1")
echo $ABC
```

nothing is echo'ed, so it looks like `source` doesn't work? Any ideas?

Btw, I tried replacing source with `.` - the same problem.

Comment: Works when I run it. The output is `1`.

Comment: You will find an answer [here](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2006-01/msg00018.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple's `bash` just appears to be too old. I reproduced your failure locally, but it works fine with `bash` 5.1.16 from homebrew.

I didn't look up any specific bug fixes or version notes, though, sorry.